# Dimensional Modeling: Joining Dimensions together without a Fact Table

Tags: oracle, dimensional-modeling, star-schema, fact

I have been working in a Data Warehouse environment for a couple years. From my experience dimensions should not be joined together without a fact table. My understanding is that unless the dimensions are at the same granule level the results could be skewed. Also, joining a bunch of dimension tables together is not best practice and defeats the purpose of a star design. However, in my current environment our developers have decided to join these dimensions together anyway within a materialized view. Is there a downside to this design when the dimensions grow in size? Also, if anyone can point me in the direction of some good resources about this dilemma.

I have researched various Kimball texts and websites. I have gone back through notes from Dimensional Modeling classes but have not found any information on what happens when the star design is abandoned and materialized views are used in place of it. If this is the incorrect area for this question please let me know if there is a better forum.

Example query,

```
SELECT <COLUMNS>...
FROM D_LANGUAGE_1 DL1
INNER JOIN D_APPLICATION_INFORMATION AI ON(DL1.<JOIN KEYS> = AI.<JOIN KEY>)
INNER JOIN D_DATE D ON(D.DATE_KEY = TRUNC(AI.SUBMISSION_DATE))
LEFT OUTER JOIN D_LANGUAGE_BRG DLB ON(DL1.<JOIN KEY> = DLB.<JOIN_KEY>)
LEFT OUTER JOIN L_LANGUAGE_CAT LC ON (LC.<JOIN_KEY> = DL1.<JOIN_KEY>)
WHERE AI.CURRENT_ROW_IND = 'Y';
```

Comment: Can you provide a mock up of some of these joins so it's clearer what they are doing?

Comment: Your text seems to describe a perfectly reasonable snowflake model where dimensions snowflake off each other.  In your query, I assume you are concerned about joining the `d_application_information` dimension to `d_date`?  If so, that seems exceptionally reasonable.  Date dimensions tend to be pretty special.  If there are a number of dates in `d_application_information`, it seems very reasonable even in a star schema not to replicate all the date dimension columns to every date column in `d_application_information`.

Comment: Added an example. However, the query is much more complex than what I put as an example.

Comment: We currently do not have a snowflake design. The d_application_information and d_date are not my concern. Should fact tables never be used when querying dimensions? There are cases where no fact table is used just dimensions being joined together within a materialized view. Could this be a design that works over time?

Comment: If you have a `d_langugage_1` dimension and a `d_language_brg` dimension that joins to that dimension and `l_language_cat` (what does the l prefix mean here?) that also joins to the `d_language_1` table then I'd find it pretty hard to argue that you have a star design.  Sure looks like a snowflake from here.

Comment: Without knowing why your developers have created this MV it’s impossible to comment on whether this is good or bad practice - but in general you should stick to a specific methodology. In your case you are using star schemas so, in the face of it, this MV doesn’t follow that methodology so is, on the face of it, bad practice

Comment: @JustinCave We do have a star schema design on other older tables. However, this query here is one that was created without using the star schema methodology. There are no foreign keys between these tables. The prefix L_ means lookup. This might not be the best example of the problem.

Comment: @NickW the idea I received from the developers was that a fact table was not necessary and caused extra development. There are no fact tables being developed at this point. With the influx of data we are receiving and utilizing the SCD type 2 concept, will this method cause issues with query performance over time?

Comment: Thank you all for responding to this post. I am trying to get an idea of how this will affect long term query performance within the database. Refreshing of these Materialized views takes over 1 hour at the moment. I should note.

Comment: From a modeling perspective, `d_application_information` looks a lot like a fact table to me (having no idea what problem domain you are dealing with).  Where is the "influx of data" going?  My guess is that dates and languages are pretty stable and slow-growing over time and that the vast majority of the data is going into the pseudo-fact `d_application_information` table.  If that table is partitioned on `current_row_ind` so that all the current rows are in one partition and the majority of the table contains old historical records, this query should perform reasonably well over time.

Comment: Of course, other `d_application_information` queries might tend to do better with a different partitioning scheme.

Comment: If you are joining dimensions  together, do you not just end up with a huge cartesian product?

Comment: “a fact table was not necessary and caused extra development” is an excuse, not a reason. Unless we know what the business requirement is that triggered this work, and the analysis that went into the decision not to follow the star schema model, it’s not possible to provide any useful feedback. However, based purely on the information provided, it sounds like your developers don’t understand why star schemas are the preferred data model for analytics and so they have taken the easy path without understanding the implications